# C++ Sorting Array struct by using QuickSort

Tags: c++, vector, struct, quicksort

I have to sort the array of struct by using a QuickSort algorithm(not built-in function, i have to write it manually) and also take the measure of working time and compare with standard C++ sort function. After i compile my code the output file(sort.txt) looks the same. What have i done wrong?

```
struct Info
{
    int Birth;
    char Name[20];
    char SurName[25];
};

template <keys T>
struct Comparer {

    bool operator ()(const Info &m1, const Info &m2) const {

        return (T == YEAR ? m1.Birth > m2.Birth : strcmp(m1.Name, m2.Name) > 0);
    }

};

int partition(vector<Info> &vArray, int start, int end) {
    int pivotValue, pivotIndex, mid;

    mid = (start + end) / 2;
    swap(vArray[start].Birth, vArray[mid].Birth);
    swap(vArray[start].Name, vArray[mid].Name);
    swap(vArray[start].SurName, vArray[mid].SurName);


    pivotIndex = start;
    pivotValue = vArray[start].Birth;

    for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++) {
        if (vArray[scan].Birth < pivotValue) {
            pivotIndex++;
            swap(vArray[pivotIndex].Birth, vArray[scan].Birth);
            swap(vArray[pivotIndex].Name, vArray[scan].Name);
            swap(vArray[pivotIndex].SurName, vArray[scan].SurName);

        }
    }

    swap(vArray[start].Birth, vArray[pivotIndex].Birth);
    swap(vArray[start].Name, vArray[pivotIndex].Name);
    swap(vArray[start].SurName, vArray[pivotIndex].SurName);
    return pivotIndex;
}

template <keys T>
void quickSort(vector<Info>&vArray, int start, int end) {
    int pivotPoint;
    if (start < end) {

        pivotPoint = partition(vArray, start, end);

        quickSort<T>(vArray, start, pivotPoint - 1);

        quickSort<T>(vArray, pivotPoint + 1, end);
    }
}

void Print(const vector<Info> Mas)
{
    string path = "sort.txt";
    ofstream Out;
    Out.open(path);
    if (!Out.is_open()) {
        cout << "wdw" << endl;

    }
    else  {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Mas.size(); i++)
            Out << Mas[i].Name << " " << Mas[i].SurName << " " << Mas[i].Birth << "\n";
    }
    Out.close();
}

template<keys T>
bool isSorted(vector<Info> Mas)
{
    Comparer<T> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < Mas.size() - 1; i++)
        if (c(Mas[i], Mas[i + 1]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

In main function:

```
        quickSort<YEAR>(Mas, 0, pow(rows, i));

    Print(Mas);
```

My full code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/e2z3l7E0

Names.txt and Surnames.txt to generate: https://dropmefiles.com/riOmD

Comment: Apart from the obvious bug that I pointed out in my answer. Get used to making a [mcve] when you ask questions. What is `keys` in `template <keys T>` for example?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So thr key is YEAR in my case.

Comment: What type is `keys`?  Don't make us quess. Put enough code in the question for others to be able to compile it.

Comment: You can find my full code here codepile.net/pile/qAKEJ4XK

Comment: That's not how it's working. People are rarely willing to read through a lot of working code to find the part that is failing. Especially when you use non-standard things like `conio.h` etc. Not many can compile that code. You are supposed to post the smallest piece of code needed for people to help you here. Create a [mcve] out of your full code. Check that it also fails - and put _that_ code in the question. If you are unsure if you've included non-standard parts, use a [good online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/HMPYJM) and try compiling it there before updating your question.

Comment: Btw, I just glanced at your full code and noticed it still has the bug I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: It's quite strange but when i swap start and end in main quickSort<YEAR>(Mas, 0, 10000);   It shows that vector is out of range.

Comment: That's because you have more than one bug. You do understand that by calling it like this: `quickSort<YEAR>(Mas, 100000, 0);` there will be **no** sorting? `start` is `>` than `end` so the condition in the `if` statement will be `false`. Right?

How many elements do you have i `vector<Info> Mas`? Make a [mcve] so that we can compile the same code as you and this will probably be solved quickly.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example depends on IDLE you using. Also i use Generate function with .txt files(names,surnames) for generation an unsorted file Data.txt. So now i have reduced my code as it possible. You can check it here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/xRBp036k

Comment: That's not a [mcve] unless you suspect that the code that fails has anything to do with the non-standard `<conio.h>` functions etc. The `<chrono>` parts making timings isn't part of a minimal example either. Make it compile with a standard compiller, https://godbolt.org/z/KdncC-  then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58979156/edit) the question and put that code in there.

Comment: You should also turn on more warnings. You have a lot of conversions between types, `unsigned` and `signed`, `floats` and `int`s. That's usually not a good sign. When you loop an index varianble, instead of casting the return value from the `size()` function to an `int`, declare your index variable as `size_t` or `auto`.

Comment: And what is `swapChar(*vArray[start].Name, *vArray[mid].Name);` doing do you think? Did you test it? It swaps the first character in the character arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much for advice. My entire code is based on this algorithm :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730549/sorting-swapping-elements-of-vector-of-structs-for-quicksort-algorithm-c

Comment: You are welcome! Please see my additions to my answer too. Found some bugs that need attention :-) Btw, use the standard swap function:  `std::swap(vArray[start].Name, vArray[mid].Name);`.for swapping. You don't need to write your own.

Comment: Did you also read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c) in the comments? It's very long but has a lot of good stuff in it.

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for your time. Sure to read this later.

Comment: Have you compiled my code succeed?

Comment: Yes, but as I mention in my answer, it has some bugs that I point out.
Here's what I compiled https://godbolt.org/z/ftKsZB
I've made a lot of changes, but not fixed your bugs. If you use `g++` or `clang++` compile with the `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address` options to see the error more clearly.

Comment: I have just complied your suggested option and got "vector out of range" error. I checked again the entire code. Can`t really find the issue and solution.

Comment: The code I shared still has the bug I pointed out in my answer: "_`vArray[1]` is illegal when `vArray.size()` is `1`_". Did you compile with the suggested options? Did you see the added output that shows that you are indexing the vector out of range (as I mentioned in my answer)?

Comment: I assume when vArray.size() is 1 only vArray[0] is legal. Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct. `[0, size())` is the valid subscript operator range.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You'll have to make changes in the implementation of the algorithm you are using to not do indexing out of bounds. One option could be to use `std::sort` instead of implementing quicksort based on code that you don't fully understand. Or make the implementation yourself from start. In that case everything should be fully understood.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the goal of the program was to write my own sorting function and implement it for a vector of structs

Comment: Then I think you would be better off writing it from scratch, following some pseudo code examples like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Answer (score 1):

These parts guarantees that no sorting will be done:

```
if (start < end) { 
//... do the sorting
} // else don't
```

```
//                   start  end                      
quickSort<YEAR>(Mas, 100000, 0);
```

In your `partition()` function, you could add some debug prints to get you on the right track:

```
    int pivotValue, pivotIndex, mid;

    mid = (start + end) / 2;
    std::cout << "size: " << vArray.size() << " start: " << start << " mid: " << mid
              << " end: " << end << "\n";
    // ...

    for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++) {
        std::cout << "scan: " << scan << "\n";
        // ...
```

What you will notice is that you are actually indexing out of bounds:

```
size: 1 start: 0 mid: 0 end: 1
scan: 1
```

`vArray[1]` is illegal when `vArray.size()` is `1` so the program has undefined behaviour.

Your `Info` has a `char Name[10]` member which means that only names up to 9 characters long can be stored in it. Your `names.txt` file contains 59 names that are longer. You will therefor write out of bounds, probably into the following `SurName` member.